# Put a Nav bar inside a SVG background

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have this SVG as my header background and put a Logo and Nav bar inside or on top of this SVG.

SVG Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1366 420" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 420;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#DBDBDC;}
    .st1{fill:#8B8BFF;}
    .st2{fill:#8C8BFF;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M5.14,236.82l1361,6.25v61.72c0,0-335,135.16-690,85.24c-161.14-22.66-465-82.3-676-100.68"/>
<path class="st1" d="M839.14,210.25"/>
<path class="st2" d="M0.14,278.23l0-278.13l1366,0v290.63c0,0-312,148.44-750.5,75.39C278.57,309.97,0.14,278.23,0.14,278.23z"/>
</svg>
```

My Header Code:

```
<div class="d-flex container-fluid">
      
        <div class="col-2">
            <div><a href="#"><img src="images/Logo-1.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 ">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
    
            <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
            
       </ul>
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <div><button class="button" >My Account</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried many ways to place this header code on SVG but it didn't work.

If anyone could suggest a better way instead of using SVG that would work just as like as this one that would be appreciated too.

Thanks in Advance and sorry for my bad English

This is what I have done so far

```
<div class="header__navbar">

<div class="svg-background-class">

        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                 viewBox="0 0 1366 420" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 420;" xml:space="preserve">
    
            <path class="st0" d="M5.14,236.82l1361,6.25v61.72c0,0-335,135.16-690,85.24c-161.14-22.66-465-82.3-676-100.68"/>
            <path class="st1" d="M839.14,210.25"/>
            <path class="st2" d="M0.14,278.23l0-278.13l1366,0v290.63c0,0-312,148.44-750.5,75.39C278.57,309.97,0.14,278.23,0.14,278.23z"/>
        </svg>

</div>

<!-- header--> 
    <div class="d-flex container-fluid">
      
        <div class="col-2">
            <div><a href="#"><img src="images/Logo-1.png" /></a></div> <!-- Logo Here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 "> <!-- menu Here -->
            
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done in many ways As you can play with position of elements.
I have written Pseudocode and comment please do check, If not clear pin me I will try to explain again.

```
<div class="header__navbar"> // this is position relative
<div class="svg-background-class"></div>//this is position absolute with right 0;
<div class="d-flex container-fluid">
      
        <div class="col-2">
            <div><a href="#"><img src="images/Logo-1.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 ">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
    
            <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
            
       </ul>
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <div><button class="button" >My Account</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can adjust according to your need.
When you use position relative- its like Ground you are standing on (Ground: parent) and 
when you do position absolute - its like person standing on above Ground (person: child with respect to Ground:parent).

and when you use 'position' property make sure you need to define size, and with top left right button you can set position

Comment: Here is clip of my code, i have done similar smth like you want.
 `<div className="position-relative">
        <div className="background"></div>
<Components />
</div>`

here is css

`.background {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 635px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0px;

    z-index: -1;
    background: url(./../assets/55ae088a24c1f1433456ecf1bd7963f4.jpeg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 20%;
}`

Hope it helps

Comment: I have edited my code gauli -  please check if this is what you tried to tell me or it's not

and of course i have added CSS Codes too but not copying that here

Comment: I think you are missing some closing div. 

If your div structure is like this

`<div class="header__navbar h-position-relative"> 

<div class="svg-background-class h-position-absolute"></div>
<div class"d-flex container fluid"> </div>

</div>`
and css like:
`.h-position-relative{position:relative}
h-position-absolute{position:absolute}`

This will work :)

Answer (score 0):

are you using SVG it's not a background try to add an image in background instead of SVG code its preferable for the site and also nave bar get right positon to I to refer use background image...

add .img to your style section its will perfect as your wish

```
.img {
 
 background-image: url("paper.gif");

}

<div class="d-flex container-fluid img">
      
        <div class="col-2">
            <div><a href="#"><img src="images/Logo-1.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 ">
        <ul class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Link1</li>
            <li>Link2</li>
    
            <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
            
       </ul>
        
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <div><button class="button" >My Account</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks parth  - Using Images in the background is my last resort- I want to use as low as images I can in order to reduce the the loading time.